# Error when I add an Embedding Layer to my ANN(Keras Functional API)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, word2vec

Error looks something like this,

***InvalidArgumentError***:  indices[14,1] = -34 is not in [0, 6505)
[[node model_12/embedding_16/embedding_lookup (defined at :3) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_14552]
Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node model_12/embedding_16/embedding_lookup:
model_12/embedding_16/embedding_lookup/13394
Function call stack:
train_function

Code:

````
input_tensor = Input(shape=(train_X_ann.shape[1],))

x = layers.Embedding(6505, 300, input_length=max_length,weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(input_tensor)
y = layers.Flatten()(x)
y1 = layers.Dense(units=units,kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer)(y)
y = layers.BatchNormalization()(y1)
y = layers.Activation(activation)(y)
y = layers.Dropout(rate=drop_rate1)(y)```

Shape of the embedding matrix is (6505,300)

Shape of_train_x_ann (64687,3594)
And it looks something like this
[Snapshot of my training data which includes features too][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KeQM.png
````

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that your input (most likely what you called *train_X_ann*) must be a tensor of integers with values between 0 and 6504, which correspond to the indices of the tokens you want to embed (since you specified input_dim=6505 for the Embedding layer). Looking at the error, it seems that instead one of them is -34, which does not fall into the expected range.

I don't know how you get the input tensor, but make sure you're correctly mapping the tokens to their respective index. Negative inputs in this context do not make sense.

Comment: Added a snapshot of what my training data looks like. Can you check and tell me what might be the issue?

Comment: I'm not really sure about what you are trying to represent in your training data. Consider that embeddings make sense when you are dealing with categorical features (in general, a finite set of values that can be mapped from their representation to an integer index). The integer indices are then what is passed as input into the embedding layer. In your case it seems that you have continuous values, so I don't know why you would like to use embeddings in the first place. Take a look [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-network-embeddings-explained-4d028e6f0526) for a brief explanation.